# Why is the <ul> clearing the sidebar to the left?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Here's the code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap-1.1.1.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="sidebar">
        <div style="height: 500px; background: red;"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <div style="height: 500px; background: #eee;">
          <ul class="tabs">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and a link to the live preview: http://jsfiddle.net/7W32Z/.

Why does the border end up below the sidebar? It has to do with the clearfix applied to the `<ul class="tabs" />` element, because if I `clear: right` only, the border jumps up.

Answer (score 1):

Float `ul.tabs` and the border should be fixed.

http://jsfiddle.net/laheab/7W32Z/3/

Comment: Thanks! That does the trick. Can you offer a quick explanation of why?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure to be honest. But the `ul` element doesn't have a set `height`, and all the element inside it are floated, so it should be rendered with `height: 0`. Bootstrap add a :before pseudo -selector to the `.tabs` with `display: table` which gives `.tabs` 100% height, and that's why you see the border at the bottom. Or at least that's what I think.